# Trouble creating top and bottom horizontal border lines aligning to the text in grid layout

Tags: css, grid, alignment, line

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line without interrupting the grid layout. This is what I'm hoping to reach:

I have wrapped all the navigation elements with a grid system. As I try to create a horizontal lines from the parent element, the lines are drawn aligning to the image.

Comment: You are putting the border around the whole item, which includes the img.

Comment: On screens less than 1280px you are putting the menu items lower down than The Art of Photography. Where do you want the lines to go in that case? Also your media query means there is not setting up of grid for wider screens - is that intentional?

Comment: I have intentionally placed it as 1280px since I’ll tweak a bit later in the future. Any idea how I can exclude the image and create a horizontal border too and bottom of the texts?

Comment: OK, so the lines are just for wide screens when both the menu items and the heading are on the same line?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the lines in as pseudo elements on the navbar - giving a top and bottom offset in % terms. Note however that this does not give a sensible result when the menu is not level with the heading - but that is understood (and the reason it wont work in a SO snippet).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lab04_New</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Lab04_new.css">
  <style>
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 3fr 4fr 2fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav nav nav nav";
  }
  
  #navbar {
    grid-area: nav;
  }

  #navbar img, header, ul, li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #navbar img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }

  ul {
    float: right;
  }

  li {
    padding: 15px;
  }

}

section#navbar {
  position: relative;
  --offset: 30%;
  }
  
#navbar::before, #navbar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

#navbar::before {
  top: var(--offset);
}

#navbar::after {
  top: calc(100% - var(--offset));
}

  </style>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class = "main">
    <section id = "navbar">
      <img src="gear.jpg" alt="lens" width="90" height="90">
      <header>
        <h3>Art of Photography</h3>
      </header>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="navbar_left">Photography</div></li>
        <li><div class="navbar_left">History</div></li>
        <li><div class="navbar_right">Samples</div></li>
        <li><div class="navbar_right">About</div></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```